# Get index of object from array of dictionary with key value

Tags: ios, swift

I have one array with dictionary.

Now i want to get index number of object with particular key value.

Like key = "xyz" and value = "abc".

I need index of object having above matching in dictionary.

```
{
        Id = 20085;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Circular;
    },
        {
        Id = 20088;
        IsNew = 0;
        Title = Query;
    },
        {
        Id = 20099;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Blog;
    },
        {
        Id = 20104;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = News;
    },
        {
        Id = 20172;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = AssignTask;
    },
        {
        Id = 20183;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Gallery;
    },
        {
        Id = 20204;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Poll;
    },
        {
        Id = 20093;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Assignment;
    },
        {
        Id = 20209;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Activity;
    },
        {
        Id = 20130;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Behaviour;
    },
        {
        Id = 20180;
        IsNew = 1;
        Title = Result;
    }
```

now i need index of object with having key = "Title" and value = "result"

Comment: Could you please provide more context?

Comment: Dictionary is an inappropriate choice here. These should be structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you should be doing after using a json parser

```
 let array:NSArray = [
[
    "Id": 20130,
    "IsNew": 1,
    "Title":"Behaviour"
],
[
    "Id": 20180,
    "IsNew": 1,
    "Title":"Result"
]]


let k = array as Array
let index = k.indexOf {
    if let dic = $0 as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
        if let value = dic["Title"]  as? String
            where value == "Result"{
         return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

print(index) // index
```

Comment: Thank you , but i have NSArray

Comment: its killing me can you please help me

Comment: let arr = arrHomeUpdate as Array
                    let index = arr.indexOf{$0["Title"] == strTitle as? String}

Comment: I have updated the answer, assuming you are using an `NSArray`, and you do index you get back `AnyObject` check if the object is a dictionary then continue.

Comment: @KushThakkar Why are you even using NSArray?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`indexOf(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FEsPs14CollectionType7indexOfFzFzWx9Generator7Element_SbGSqwx5Index_) for this:

```
let index = array.indexOf{ $0["key"] == value }
```

In Swift 3.0, it's been renamed to `index(Where:)`:

```
let index = array.index{ $0["key"] == value }
```

You can see this in action [here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/9791ca761219251ff915a51807e697e0687be890a96d9f42469524f4f5613c08).

Comment: This will not check for value

Comment: Can you please add real example from above response , Thank you.

Comment: What you've shown is JSON, i'm just doing the best approximation given the very little information you give. I posted a link to a working example. Just convert the NSArray to a proper Swift Array: http://dev.eltima.com/post/96538497489/convert-nsmutablearray-to-swift-array

Comment: Correct answer and congrats for the Swift 3.0 version ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with mapping the id values to an array, then getting the index of the id you're looking for.

```
func getIndexOf(itemID: Int) -> Int {

    //Map out all the ids from the array of dictionaries into an array of Integers
    let keysArray = dictionaries.map { (dictionary) -> Int in
        return dictionary.value(forKey: "Id")
    }

    //Find the index of the id you passed to the functions
    return keysArray.index(of: itemID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

other mainstream way to do this

```
func getIndex(of key: String, for value: String, in dictionary : [[String: Any]]) -> Int{
    var count = 0
    for dictElement in dictionary{
        if dictElement.keys.contains(key) && dictElement[key] as! String == value{
            return count
        }
        else{
            count = count + 1
        }
    }
    return -1

}

var sampleDict : [[String:Any]] = [
    [
        "Id" : 20130,
        "IsNew" : 1,
        "Title" : "Behaviour"
    ],
    [
        "Id" : 20130,
        "IsNew" : 1,
        "Title" : "Result"
        ],
]

let index = getIndex(of: "Title", for: "Result", in: sampleDict)

print(index)
```

This will print 1.

Answer (score 0):

#### This answer is for the Swift 5.2  and above versions.

```
 arr.append(["Title":titleName,"ID":1,"Result":true])
 arr.append(["Title":titleName,"ID":2,"Result":true])
 arr.append(["Title":titleName,"ID":3,"Result":true])
 arr.append(["Title":titleName,"ID":4,"Result":true])
```

This is an array of dictionary format. And if you want to find an index of an object where ID == 3

```
func findIndex(Id : Int ) -> Int? {
    
    guard let index = arr.firstIndex(where: {
        if let dic = $0 as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            if let value = dic["ID"]  as? Int, value == Id {
                
                return true
            }
            
        }
        return  false
    }) else { return nil }
    return index
}

let myIndex = findIndex(3)
self.arr.insert( ["Title":titleName,"ID":10,"Result":true]) at: myIndex)
```