# get index of dictionary from array of dictionary in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

How to get a specific dictionary from array of dictionary by giving **key** alone in method.

we studied about indexOf method in array but we are not sure about how to pass **key** and get a index of particular **key**.

Here is Array of dictionary

```
[  
   {  
      "Twitter0":"NSLayoutConstraint"
   },
   {  
      "Twitter1":"NSLayoutConstraint"
   },
   {  
      "Insta2":"NSLayoutConstraint"
   },
   {  
      "Twitter3":"NSLayoutConstraint"
   },
   {  
      "Insta4":"NSLayoutConstraint"
   }
]
```

I just want to pass key name like **Twitter2** in method.

We tried this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602091/get-index-of-object-from-array-of-dictionary-with-key-value), we dont know how to process with **key**

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If each of the dictionaries in the array have different keys, why have an array? Why not just have a single dictionary with all of the keys and values?

Comment: We need to create multiple webview by iterating json response and we need to find out which webview complete its load. so we have created different key with tag. Is this wrong procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex) and pass a closure to it:

```
arrayOfDicts.firstIndex(where: { $0.keys.contains("Twitter2")})
```

Or more generally with `key`:

```
arrayOfDicts.firstIndex(where: { $0.keys.contains(key)})
```

Comment: Or using the trailing closure syntax `arrayOfDicts.firstIndex { $0.keys.contains("Twitter2") }`